# Folder metadata not synched to harmon.ie for Outlook

Tags: sharepoint, metadata, directory, harmon.ie

in SharePoint I have created a Folder Content type with additional columns (one of them a lookup column) using site columns and site Content types.
I assigned this to a library so I can now use metadata on Folders. Also I added the columns to the Standard view.
I connected to this library with harmon.ie for Outlook. At first, when creating a new Folder with metadata the lookup values etc. were also visible in the harmon.ie Panel in Outlook.
In the next step I changed the view to have a grouping on this lookup column.

From this Moment the lookup values did not appear anymore in harmon.ie. Funny Thing is - when editing the values the metadata fields are shown and I can edit and save them. In this case the metadata is also saved in harmon.ie and the Folder is in the right Group.

I guess it's a bug? Tried it with Outlook 2016, latest harmon.ie Version, with SharePoint 2010 and also Office 365/SharePoint Online.

Any ideas?

Thanks and best regards
Bernhard

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to download our latest version from our web site and set the below registry key:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\StrictViewFields]
@="true"

---- Jean

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I downloaded latest version today. I didn't find this registry key. Should I add it? Is it a DWORD32 underneath [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs] with value 1 or a String with value "true"?

Bernhard

Answer (score 0):

Simply add --all the below lines-- inside a .reg file then double click on it to register the key.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\StrictViewFields] 
@="true"